# Writing custom test framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I'm developing a kind of own `unittest` framework for external `hardware` including a testcase runner. The term hardware means, that the tests do not test software on the host - they test implementation on external hardware, on `microcontrollers`.

In `C#` unittests always declared with `attributes` rather than implementing a testcase `interface`.

My design question is which solution should I prefer for a new design?

Edit:
The reason for a custom core code is that the test case runner has something like the following behavior:

```
foreach(var tc in testcases)
    foreach(var temp in temperatures)
        SetTemperature(temp);
        foreach(var position in positions)
            GotoPosition(position);
            DoTestcase(tc);
```

Comment: Why not use a standard test framework?  Understanding why the current 'best practice' frameworks don't meet your needs may throw some light on the correct way forward.

Comment: Of course, I would do so if I could. The main problem is that the test cases needed to be done on several positions (there exists a robot place for doing that) and on many temperatures (thermo chamber). This can't be integrated to `standard` frameworks.

Comment: Obviously I don't know the details here, but what you're talking about sounds like a test setup issue. The test setup can be controlled by custom code using most frameworks (e.g. XUnit).  Unless you'll be running the test code itself on some strange hardware I'm struggling to see the need to reinvent the core of a test framework, rather than extend an existing one. In any case best practice is almost certainly the practice implemented by frameworks such as XUnit, so you may as well look at their code.

Comment: No doubt - reusing existing, working, tested code is much better than write the same again. The problem is doing a test flow like the example above. Is this possible with existing `xUnit` suites?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  You could just combine the tests into one unit test, or you can write a parameterized test (a theory in XUnit speak) which takes its data from DataAttributes.  You can implement your own version of data attributes to parameterize tests however you like.

Comment: This means the tests are multiplied up by `testcases`*`temperatures`*`position` test cases? For a testcases passes on one temperature if it passes on every position. That means that all position refer to one testcase. Since every testcase has position this not necessarily needs to be implemented inside the testcase.

Comment: You might be better just implementing these as big compound tests. It's not ideal but the only real downside is you don't get the granular reporting. But it you rolled this all yourself you'd need to develop a reporting harness (e.g. if you want to run within visual studio) and since you're unlikely to do that it's going to be the same as running one big test in XUnit.  Everything is possible with XUnit, it's just a balance of how much work you want to put in versus the benefit. But it sounds like a much better idea to me than reinventing the entire wheel.

Answer (score 2):

The old junit tests (in Java of course) were based on naming conventions,
than it started using annotatinos (attribute equivalent) instead-
which is much better, because you don't need to use naming conventions to build a test framework, that's what meta-data is for.

So, I think your case is quite similar,
why does a test case need to implement an interface?
And anyway- how would you difrrentiate between test methods and internal private methods in your test case?
Just use attributes to do so.